# Javascript Parsing Issue

Tags: javascript, newline, indexof, substr

I am trying to parse a text line by line and then parse a line on tokens with `'\t'` as the delimiter.

So far I have the following:

```js
str = "a\tb\tc\n1\t2\t3\nx\t\y\tz"
console.log( str + "\n");
    
i = 0;
j = str.indexOf( "\n", i );

sstr = str.substr( i, j );
 
tokens = sstr.split( '\t' );
    
console.log( tokens + "\n" );
    
i = j + 1;
j = str.indexOf( "\n", i ); // (*)
    
sstr = str.substr( i, j );
    
console.log( sstr + "\n");
    
tokens = sstr.split( "\t" );
console.log( tokens + "\n" ); // (**)
```

Why do I get the following:

```
1,2,3
x,y,z
```

instead of the following:

```
1,2,3
```

at `console.log( tokens + "\n" ); // (**)`

Did I make a mistake?

Comment: Why aren't you starting by splitting on `"\n"`?

Comment: @nnnnnn original `str` has 10000+ lines and I need to process it line by line consequently.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thank you. I just need `j - i` instead of `j`

Comment: Should I delete the topic as too specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `j` as the end index of the required substring, but the second argument of [`.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) is not the end index, it's the number of characters to take. (It works the first time because the start index is 0 so the end index is equal to the number of characters to take.)

Try [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) instead. (Or [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), but I prefer `.slice()` because it is more versatile, and shorter to type.)

```
sstr = str.slice( i, j );
```